# Android Google maps api : How to find out if device is inside a building or outside?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there any way to figure out if user's device is in or out of a building using Google map API for android? If there are many, in which scenario those should be used? I know I can use GPS as a hint but that costs too much battery as I will be performing indoor/outdoor check after regular intervals.

Thanks.

Comment: is it a specific building or is it any building?

Comment: Its for common buildings. For specific building i can use geofencing.

Comment: There is no way. You should use GPS as hint and is not possible to use other clue to figure out where you are. However use GPS can not be sufficient. You can use a bluetooth devices or wireless network to understand if you device is inside a building. I suggest you to use fused location api https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi in combination with bluetooth/wifi (if the device is not generic)